# Image preloading isn't working for images in FireFox

Tags: javascript, image, image-preloader

I'm dynamically switching background images. Naturally, they need to be preloaded to display promptly. I am preloading them, am able to following in FireBug as the images load. When the background image switches, I see the images download again in FireBug.

Here's my url: http://www.morganpackard.com/siteRoot/

Strangely, if I reload the page, everything works as expected. The steps I'm taking are as follows:

1) clear FireFox cache
2) reload page
   Images load slowly, and, apparently are neither being preloaded nor cached. Every time there's an image swap, the image downloads again.
3) now reload the page again without clearing the cache
    Images load and swap instantly, everything works as expected.

So it looks like I'm having to RELOAD before FireFox will read images from the cache. This is kooky. Any ideas?

Note: My images are ENORMOUS. I'll compress them, of course, but want to get this preloading this sorted first.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't read your code, but for preloading to work, you must add the image to the document DOM, otherwise it can be garbage collected aggressively.

Comment: Hmmm. But the classic JS preload just creates JS image objects, without adding them to the DOM. Just to make sure, I tried literally appending my images to the dom, making them visible. So I see ImageA on the screen, obviously loaded in the DOM, but when I set the background to ImageA, there's a pause while it downloads again.

Comment: I think Nicholas is correct; I typically add preloaded images to DOM elements removed from view.

Comment: When you set your background-image, are you sure you use the same url than the image you just preloaded? You might try using image.src (as image is the one you preloaded), also be sure to do that when the image is loaded.

Otherwise I don't know.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah, everything you've suggested checks out. I added a comment to my original question outlining an additional strangeness -- that my images are read correctly from the cache AFTER I reload.

Answer (score 2):

Checking with HttpFox, I am **not** seeing further http requests - when clicking around - for your background images after the initial load. If I hit "refresh" then the images are reloaded. I think this is correct and what you'd expect. However be aware that reloading of a page and its assets like images, css etc on a page refresh is dependent on both response headers and any over-rides for these specified in your browser/plugin tools. Take a look at pragma: no-cache and [W3C Cache-Control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (Section 14.9)

Edit: With firebug on, I *am* seeing reloads when I click around. This is presumably an artefact of Firebug. Turn off firebug and you wont have the reloads.

Comment: I've turned FireBug off, and the images are still loading slowly. Works as expected in Safari, but not firefox.